# function sent to other functions as arguments

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I was reading a book on react and was on functional programming chapter when I encountered this.

```
const insideFn = logger =>
    logger("They can be sent to other functions as arguments");
insideFn(message => console.log(message))
// They can be sent to other functions as arguments
```

Now I am quite confused:

1. The output of `insideFn` is argument of `logger` function, just an argument, it is not being returned from `logger` function. So why is the output of `insideFn`, argument of `logger`?
2. I tried to check the type of `message` - result was string. Why is it string? isn't `message` a function?
3. I expected when we do `console.log` of  message it should return function definition of `logger`, but it returns its argument? This doesn't make sense to me?

Thank you for explaining.

Comment: `logger("They can be sent to other functions as arguments")` — that is a **call** to the function passed as an argument.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "*The output of insideFn is argument of logger function*", can you elaborate? Are you talking about the return value of `insideFn`?

Comment: "*Why is it string? isnt message a function?*" - no, `logger` is the function, `message` is the string that you pass to it.

Comment: Thank you @Pointy for the answer. I am still confused why the argument of logger function i.e. "They can be sent to other functions as arguments" is being printed?

Comment: Because in `insideFn()` is called with the function `message => console.log(message)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrow functions make this a bit confusing. Maybe a more verbose example would be clearer:

```
function insideFn(logger) {
    logger("inside's log message");
    // some computation here
    return 42;
}

function myLogger(message) {
    console.log(message);
}
insideFn(myLogger);
```

Comment: Your code makes sense, but somehow the code I have written above still doesnt click. I will try to understand it again tmrw. Thank you for the explanation everybody.